# How to clear a bytes.Buffer that is set as StdOut in exec.Command in Golang (b.Reset is not working)

Tags: go, buffer, exec, stdout, stdin

I'm trying to write a command line application wrapper in GoLang that exposes a REST API to interact with said application and show its output.

Basically when the REST API server starts, it should start a command line application that keeps running (As an example just *Powershell.exe*) and should be able to interact with the application and show its output when requested trough the API.

So far the server starts, the child process also starts, and I'm able to issue commands to the process and retrieve its output. To capture the output of the process I'm using a *bytes.Buffer* that I attach to the processes *Stdout* and *Stderr*.

The problem is that that output buffer seems to be growing into infinite, and there is no way to clear it. Running "*.Reset()*" on that buffer seems to be completely ignored, and the full buffered output is always shown.

Here is the code:

```
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "os/exec"
)

func main() {

    var c = exec.Command("powershell.exe")
    var b bytes.Buffer
    c.Stdout = &b
    c.Stderr = &b

    stdin, err := c.StdinPipe()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    http.HandleFunc("/", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        fmt.Fprintf(w, "Do stuff")
    })

    http.HandleFunc("/clear", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        fmt.Fprintf(w, "Cleared")
        b.Reset()
    })

    http.HandleFunc("/write", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        stdin.Write([]byte("echo hi\n"))
        fmt.Fprintf(w, "OK")
    })

    http.HandleFunc("/show", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        fmt.Fprintf(w, string(b.Bytes()))
    })

    fmt.Println("SERVER 1 STARTING")
    c.Start()
    c.CombinedOutput()
    http.ListenAndServe(":8081", nil)
    fmt.Println("SERVER 1 STOPPED")

}
```

So the expected behavior here is that when you call "*/write*" it will execute "echo hi" in the child application. "*/show*" will show the output buffer of the application. and "*/clear*" should clear the output buffer, so that when you run "*/write*", then "*/clear*" and then "*/show*", an empty string should be shown. But in this case, it keeps showing the application output that never gets cleared.

Interestingly if I manually write into the buffer via *b.WriteString()* and then I do the *b.Reset()*, that content does gets erased, but not the content from the command line application.

Is there some way to properly clear the bytes.Buffer when it's attached to Stdout/Stderr? Or alternatively, is there some way to limit the buffer to a specific number of lines?

Comment: You have absolutely no synchronization here, so it's likely you are seeing the the result of a data race. `bytes.Buffer` says nothing about being safe for concurrent use.

Comment: bytes.Buffer is not going to work for the reason noted by JimB.  To help get you headed in the right direction, we need to know how much data an application should read after sending input.  Does the application read until newline or something else?

Comment: Input and Output should be completely independent, in other words, executing "/write" should not wait till the command gets completed (I'll update the example to reflect that). "/show" will be polled every few seconds for updates. Also the wrapped application may print output without issuing commands (Log is outputted). How can it have a race condition when no new output is generated by the child process and you Reset the buffer? (I'm assuming for my example only one user calling the API one at a time). I must be missing out some detail here.. "/clear" has a race condition?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@JimB is correct, this appears to be a synchronization problem. It's not the webserver, but how exec.Command works, and how the buffer is shared.

This program might help explain. It runs ping and reads the buffer every second, attempting to reset the buffer each time. Ping is writing to the buffer every second.

```
func main() {
    cmd := exec.Command("ping", "google.com")
    var buf bytes.Buffer
    cmd.Stdout = &buf

    err := cmd.Start()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    for i := 0; i < 3; i++ {
        time.Sleep(1 * time.Second)
        log.Println(buf.String())
        buf.Reset()
    }

    cmd.Process.Kill()
}
```

But the output is accumulated each time, as if the call to buf.Reset() call is ignored:

> ```
> $ go run main.go 
> 2020/01/28 22:05:25 PING google.com(syd09s13-in-x0e.1e100.net (2404:6800:4006:807::200e)) 56 data bytes
> 64 bytes from syd09s13-in-x0e.1e100.net (2404:6800:4006:807::200e): icmp_seq=1 ttl=50 time=50.3 ms
>
> 2020/01/28 22:05:26 PING google.com(syd09s13-in-x0e.1e100.net (2404:6800:4006:807::200e)) 56 data bytes
> 64 bytes from syd09s13-in-x0e.1e100.net (2404:6800:4006:807::200e): icmp_seq=1 ttl=50 time=50.3 ms
> 64 bytes from syd09s13-in-x0e.1e100.net (2404:6800:4006:807::200e): icmp_seq=2 ttl=50 time=52.0 ms
>
> 2020/01/28 22:05:27 PING google.com(syd09s13-in-x0e.1e100.net (2404:6800:4006:807::200e)) 56 data bytes
> 64 bytes from syd09s13-in-x0e.1e100.net (2404:6800:4006:807::200e): icmp_seq=1 ttl=50 time=50.3 ms
> 64 bytes from syd09s13-in-x0e.1e100.net (2404:6800:4006:807::200e): icmp_seq=2 ttl=50 time=52.0 ms
> 64 bytes from syd09s13-in-x0e.1e100.net (2404:6800:4006:807::200e): icmp_seq=3 ttl=50 time=57.1 ms
> ```

The bytes.Buffer can be replaced with a synchronized buffer, where the writes and reads are protected by a mutex. This is a bit simplistic, but for example:

```
type SyncBuf struct {
    mu  sync.Mutex
    buf bytes.Buffer
}

func (s *SyncBuf) Write(p []byte) (int, error) {
    s.mu.Lock()
    defer s.mu.Unlock()
    return s.buf.Write(p)
}

func (s *SyncBuf) Reset() {
    s.mu.Lock()
    defer s.mu.Unlock()
    s.buf.Reset()
}

func (s *SyncBuf) String() string {
    s.mu.Lock()
    defer s.mu.Unlock()
    return s.buf.String()
}
```

When the buffer is replaced, the output behaves as expected, respecting the Reset() call:

> ```
> $ go run main.go 
> 2020/01/28 22:07:03 PING google.com(syd09s13-in-x0e.1e100.net (2404:6800:4006:807::200e)) 56 data bytes
> 64 bytes from syd09s13-in-x0e.1e100.net (2404:6800:4006:807::200e): icmp_seq=1 ttl=50 time=50.4 ms
>
> 2020/01/28 22:07:04 64 bytes from syd09s13-in-x0e.1e100.net (2404:6800:4006:807::200e): icmp_seq=2 ttl=50 time=51.8 ms
>
> 2020/01/28 22:07:05 64 bytes from syd09s13-in-x0e.1e100.net (2404:6800:4006:807::200e): icmp_seq=3 ttl=50 time=50.8 ms
> ```

See [full example](https://play.golang.org/p/SKNYRWKVQO4) on playground.

Disclaimer: this is posted as an illustration, it may not be a good solution to your problem.